# matlab plot data in a functional way

Tags: matlab

I got some data like this,

```
 76.09879   87.42057    1.00000
 84.43282   43.53339    1.00000
 95.86156   38.22528    0.00000
 75.01366   30.60326    0.00000
 82.30705   76.48196    1.00000
 69.36459   97.71869    1.00000
 39.53834   76.03681    0.00000
 53.97105   89.20735    1.00000
 69.07014   52.74047    1.00000
 67.94686   46.67857    0.00000
 70.66151   92.92714    1.00000
 76.97878   47.57596    1.00000
 67.37203   42.83844    0.00000
```

what I want to do is to plot all these points with the first as X and the second as Y,
and if the third value is 0 plot with a 'ko' as parameter else use 'k+'

I wonder if I can use a functional style code like

```
plot(data(:,1),(:,2),%a  function to turn 0 to 'k0',1 to 'k+');
```

to plot the data?

ps: I use mathematica a lot, that's the reason why I am asking this kind of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can do:

```
plot(data(data(:,3)==1,1), data(data(:,3)==1,2), 'k+', ...
     data(data(:,3)==0,1), data(data(:,3)==0,2), 'ko')
```

Or this but this is uglier:

```
plot(data(logical(data(:,3)),1), data(logical(data(:,3)),2), 'k+', ...
     data(!logical(data(:,3)),1), data(!logical(data(:,3)),2), 'ko')
```

Comment: but I still wonder why it's not possible to use a function which can take the argument when plotting the data like that I can do in mathematica? can you explain that

Comment: There is no particular reason. The [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function is not designed like that, that's it. If you need you can always write your own function to improve it (or search the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), such a function might exist)!

Answer (score 2):

```
positive = find(y==1);
negative = find(y==0);

plot(X(positive,1),X(positive,2),'k+');
plot(X(negative,1),X(negative,2),'ko');
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.